# How to detect changes to PHAuthorizationStatus?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, photos

I need to detect changes to my app's permission to access Photos using PhotoKit on iOS 8. I can get the status with `PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()`, but I need to know when this status changes, so I can update the UI (which is asking them to change the permissions).

If the user launches the app, I check the `authorizationStatus` in `viewDidLoad`, then display the message if the status is `.Denied` or `.Restricted`. But if the user then goes to Settings and grants access, when they return to the app it is still showing that message. I need to handle those status changes - if it changes to `.Authorized` I need to remove the message and reload my collection view.

I couldn't find any notification I could subscribe to. How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered when I run the app on a real device as opposed to debugging in the Simulator, when the user changes the photo access permission, the app seems to be terminated because when they return to the app it is not resumed where they were before. Because I request authorization in `viewDidLoad` for the first view controller, it properly handles the denied/restricted statuses.

Note that if you're debugging the app in the Simulator when testing this, it will not terminate it. But if you stop running the app then try it, it will terminate it.

Comment: Right. The app is restarted on the real device after you change PHAuthorizationStatus from Settings App.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to handle this now with deep linking on iOS 9+?  When I set photo permissions and return to app via the back button in iOS status bar, app crashes.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check for empty `PHFetchResult` objects, whenever you attempt to utilise PhotoKit.

This is because, if the user has denied your app photo library access, not yet responded to the permission prompt, or cannot grant access due to restrictions, any attempts to fetch photo library content will return empty `PHFetchResult` objects.

Apple recommends that you use `registerChangeObserver:` because

> ... After the user grants access to the photo library for your app, Photos sends change messages for any empty fetch results you retrieved beforehand, notifying you that library content for those fetches is now available.

You can find out more here [PhotoKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014404-CH1-DontLinkElementID_9).

Comment: That would work, but you wouldn't know if they've denied access or if their device has that access restricted and there's nothing they can do to enable it themselves. It's best to display different messages to the user for those two cases.